# обращение к файлу в другой директории

Tags: java, файлы

как я могу обратиться к файлу "sensitive_data.txt", находящегося в директории /resources из файла проекта SimpleRegExpService.java[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы иметь доступ к файлу, его нужно добавить в проект в Assets и потом из кода вызывать. 2) в Gradle определить папку ассетов типа: `android {
    sourceSets {
        main.assets.srcDirs += '../myAssetsFolder'
    }
}`